# Xamarin Android: how to add buttons to recyclerview

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi.
I made a recycler view and i wonder if is possible to include buttons that is shown in the botton of page like a botton navigation view  when a item is selected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.Could you please post more details about your question?

Comment: Hello thanks for answering Jessie Zhang, i couldnt insert a image in this question but i could atach an image in this xamarin comunity question, in that question  i explain better what i am tryng to do.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/386735#Comment_386735

Comment: You can use `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to  achieve this.Just overlay the layout on the recyclerview ,when you selected a Item, then show the layout, otherwise hide it.

Comment: in the layout do i insert buttons or that is a menu ?

Comment: Yes, you can insert the buttons in the layout  just as you want. I've done this before in my app.

Comment: But how i show a botton that is in mainactivity in a recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the layout in the botton of the mainactivity layout.
Since I don't have the full code of your app,so I use a demo to show the function.
You can get the full demo  [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/multiselecteDemo).
The main  code is as follows

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/below_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn_mover"
        android:text="Mover"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:background="#90909090"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator1" />

    <TextView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn_lido"
        android:text="Lido"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:background="#90909090"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator2" />
    <TextView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn_apagar"
        android:text="Apagar"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The effect is:
[image]

Note:

1. The implementation in RecyclerView is similar, you can try to achieve it.
   If you have any problem, I am willing to help you.
2. The demo refers to this article: https://sabitlabscode.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/xamarin-android-multi-select-with-contextual-action-bar-cab/

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jessie Zhang this suits my need, i wont be able to text until tomorrow, but until monday i comment if worked.